# Maximise Dock to full width

Tags: macos, dock

I'm a new user of Macintosh and I'm trying to set the Dock to full width from the center of screen, like with KDE on Linux operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [**cDock**](http://w0lfschild.github.io/app_cDock.html).

[image]

Install, enable and choose Fullscreen width Dock.

[image]

Comment: Is this a paid software?

Comment: @Sai Yes with 7 day free trial

Comment: Any free alterative?

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be [uBar](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar).

[image]

You can read more about it from the website and/or get the trial.

I'd claim that this works better for people who like to keep nothing but open applications in the dock. That's the way I use it.

My favorite features are:

- Manual sorting.

  - Like for example, all adobe applications are always next to each other no matter which order they are opened it.
- App exclusion (hiding)

  - I have some applications that I exclusively show and hide via shortcut toggle, so it's really handy for that. No extra clutter from those apps.
- Window preview
- I really like the keyboard shortcuts, like`Shift` clicking an app will make it quit. `cmd+shift` clicking will force restart.

One con is I would say that if you like to use spaces, you have to every now and then show the native Dock (`cmd+alt+D`), to assign a different space to application. Not really a big deal though. Read more about that here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21872?locale=en_US

---

uBar 4 is fresh enough that I don't have it yet. I'm not 100% sure if this part below applies to it, but I'm pretty sure it does.

Not really a downside, but is a bit funny that to get a good experience, you need to hide native Dock and use a bash command to make sure it isn't accidentally shown if you hover over the Dock edge. [They mention this in the documentation.](https://brawersoftware.com/products/ubar/documentation)

Just open `Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` and paste in the two lines. Make sure the second line executes, you may have to press enter once.

```
# Hide Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool true && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 1000 && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE && killall Dock

# Restore Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide -bool false && killall Dock
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay && killall Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool FALSE && killall Dock
```

My own two additiongs to this bash command thing is the first line and second line.

1. First line just enables autohide
2. Second line sets a delay, so that the native Dock doesn't show itself if you accidentally hover over the edge, where it is hidden.
3. Attention seeking apps will sometimes bounce and start peeking from the bottom, even though autohide is on. So the third line takes care of that.

Comment: New mac users who are interested in similar customization + different productivity options should probably check out these apps as well: [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/), [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/), [Path Finder](https://cocoatech.com/), [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/), [Hyperswitch](https://bahoom.com/hyperswitch), [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/), [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com), [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/), [Launchbar](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar), [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/).